# How to create multiple data sources dynamically in spring boot(while application running) and associate transaction manager for each data source

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Need to create multiple entity managers dynamically and whenever a specific entity manager is used then corresponding transaction manager should to be picked automatically by spring container. I could create entity managers dynamically and handle the transactions manually using entityManager.getTransaction.begin() and commit() methods, but @Transaction does not work here as Entity Manager created dynamically.

Basically I need do something like given below.

```
@Transaction
private void saveEmployee(EntityManager entityManager2)
{
    Employee employee = new Employee("TestName"); //entity object

    entityManager2.save(employee); /** Container should pickup associated 
                                       Transaction Manager automatically 
                                       for handling this transaction **/
}
```

Comment: Do you want to create a pool of entityManager and transactionManager before hand and use it dynamically passing the objects to functions?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, I want to create a pool of entity Managers (and associated transaction Managers) at run time, also I should be able add/remove entity managers at run time. When i use a specific entity manager, spring container should pickup associated Transaction manager to handle the transaction